# How to get Next.JS .env variables on client-side without exposing them

Tags: next.js, .env

I had a challenge accessing `.env` variables on client-side without exposing keys in the browser. After some reading I found that `next.config.js` has access to the server-side and the client-side has access to `next.config.js` variables. So adding variables to your `next.config.js` can be accessed in the client-side.

Comment: By making .env variables available on the client side, they will be "exposed" to the client, i.e. the browser. The browser needs them to make the JavaScript run. So having stuff on the client side without exposing them in the browser is a contradiction in itself.

Answer (score 4):

To add environment variables to the JavaScript bundle, open `next.config.js` and add the env config:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: process.env.keyName, // pulls from .env file
  },
  async rewrites() {...}
}
```

Now you can access process.env.customKey in your code. For example:

```
function Page() {
  return <h1>The value of customKey is: {process.env.customKey}</h1> // has access to next.config.js
}
```

For more info:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env